# Batch fetch in hibernate by changing only place holder

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

In Simple JDBC (with no Hibernate)
we can do batch select by changing only place holder, like this

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
    "select id, name from users where id = ?");
for ( int i=0; i < 10; i++ ) {
  stmt.setInt(i);  // or whatever values you are trying to query by
  // execute statement and get result
}
```

How we can do it in Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most common and user friendly way. It use colon followed by a parameter name (:example) to define a named parameter

### Example 1: Using setParameter() method

```
String hql = "from Student s where s.registerNumner = :registerNumner";
List result = session.createQuery(hql).setParameter("registerNumner", "12345").list();
```

The setParameter() method is smart enough to discover the parameter data type of bind variable.

### Example 2: Using setString() method

You can use setString to tell Hibernate this parameter date type is String.

```
String hql = "from Student s where s.registerNumber = :registerNumber";
List result = session.createQuery(hql).setString("registerNumber", "12345").list();
```

### Example 3: Using setProperties() method

This feature is great ! You can pass an object into the parameter binding. Hibernate will automatic check the object’s properties and match with the colon parameter.

```
Student student = new Student();
Student.setRegisterNumber("12345");

String hql = "from Strudent s where s.registerNumber = :registerNumber";
List result = session.createQuery(hql).setProperties(student).list();
```

### Example 4:

You can use positional parameters also.

```
String hql = "from Student s where s.registerNumber = ? and s.studentName = ?";
List result = session.createQuery(hql).setString(0, "12345").setParameter(1, "Harshad").list();
```

But it’s vulnerable to easy breakage because every change of the position(i.e. index) of the bind parameters requires a change to the parameter binding code

### Batch select:

You can use following way for batch select

```
String hql = "from Users s where s.id= :userId";
List finalResult = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0; i< 10;i++){
   List result = session.createQuery(hql).setParameter("userId", i).list();
   finalResult.addCollection(result );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps you out,

```
 String hql = "from Users s where s.id= :userId";

 for(int i=0; i< 10;i++){
 List result = session.createQuery(hql)
    .setParameter("userId", i)
    .list();
}
```